# After I print from the struct using a file it doesn't work

Tags: c, file, struct, printf

a-  Read and print the data from the file "detyra_day.dat"

b-  Add another citizen when you know the IDNR is unique

c-  Change the information of a citizen without changing IDNR

d-  Create a "Permit to go outside" application for only 1 person per family per day
(the applicant can apply for another family member and the applicant must be over 18 years old)
and the "Permit to go outside" is granted from 8:00 to 17:00 which lasts 2 hours.

e-  Check if a citizen does have permission to go outside (print IDNR, date and time).

f-  Save

g-  Print all "Permissions to go outside" for all citizens and families.

h-  Print the list of 10 citizens that asked for the permission the most and 10 that asked the least (exclude the ones that didn't asked at all)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h> 
#include <windows.h>
int permission;
int hour;
int minute;
int nr_people;

struct citizen{
    char idnr[10];
    char name[50];
    char lname[50];
    long int birthday;
    int id_family;
};


struct birthday{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};


char fname[]={"detyra_day.dat"};



void readPeopleInfo(){
nr_people=0;
struct citizen s;
FILE *f;
f=fopen(fname,"r");
printf("\n========================================================\n\n");
printf("\t\t Details of all citizen \n\n");
printf("========================================================\n\n");

printf("IDNR\tname\tlname\tbirthday\tid_family\n\n");


if(f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(fread(&s,sizeof(struct citizen),1,f))
    {
        printf("%s\t",s.idnr);
        printf("%s\t",s.name);
        printf("%s\t",s.lname);
        printf("%ld\t",s.birthday);
        printf("%d\t\n\n",s.id_family);
        nr_people++;
    }

fclose(f);
printf("========================================================\n\n");
printf("Number of citizen = %d",nr_people);
}




void add(){
struct citizen s,s1;
int nr_people=5;
int found=0;

printf("\n Give the unique IDNR: ");
scanf("%s",&s1.idnr);
for(int i=0;i<nr_people;i++){
    if(s1.idnr==s.idnr){
        printf("The citizen with this IDNR exist");
        found=1;
        return;
    }
}
if(found==0){
    printf("The citizen with this IDNR doesn't 'exist");
    strcpy(s.idnr,s1.idnr);
  printf("\nGive the name of the citizen: ");   
  scanf("%s",s.name);
  printf("\n Give the lname of the citizen: "); 
  scanf("%s",s.lname);
  printf("\n Give the birthday of the citizen in the format YYYYMMDD: ");
  scanf("%ld",&s.birthday); 
  printf("\n Give the ID of the family of the citizen: ");
  scanf("%d",&s.id_family);
  nr_people++;
}
}




void change(){
    struct citizen s[50];
  char *idnr;
  printf("\n IDNR of citizen: ");
  scanf("%s",&idnr);
  for(int i=0;i<nr_people; i++){
    if (strcmp(s[i].idnr,idnr)==0){
    printf("\nGive the name of the citizen: ");   
    scanf("%s",s[i].name);
    printf("\n Give the lname of the citizen: "); 
    scanf("%s",s[i].lname); 
    printf("\n Give the birthday of the citizen in the format YYYYMMDD: ");
    scanf("%ld",&s[i].birthday);
    printf("\n Give the ID of the family of the citizen: ");
    scanf("%d",&s[i].id_family);             
    printf("\n Changed succesfully.");
    return; }
    printf("\n The change didn't happened.");
   }    
}




void permit(){
    int permission;
    struct birthday bday;
    struct citizen s[50];
    int age[nr_people];
    SYSTEMTIME d;
    GetLocalTime(&d);
    for(int i=0;i<nr_people;i++){
        if(bday.month>d.wMonth||(bday.month==d.wMonth&&bday.day>=d.wDay)){
        age[i]=d.wYear-bday.year;
    }
    else{
        age[i]=d.wYear-bday.year-1;
    }
    }
    char *name;
    char *lname;
    char *chosenperson;
    int id_family;
    int i;
    int apply=0;
    int familymembers=0;
    printf("Put your name: ");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("Put your lname: ");
    scanf("%s",&lname);
    for (i=0;i<nr_people;i++){
    if((strstr(name,s[i].name)==0&&strstr(lname,s[i].lname)==0&&age[i]>=18)){
        printf("Your name is on the list and you are in the age to apply");
        id_family=s[i].id_family;
        apply=1;
    }
}
    if(apply==0){
        printf("Your name is not on the list or you are not in the age to apply");
        return;
    }
    struct citizen tmp;
    for(i=0;i<nr_people;i++){
        if(id_family==s[i].id_family){
            tmp=s[50];
            familymembers++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<familymembers;i++){
        printf("%d. name: %10s",i+1,tmp.name);
    }
    apply=0;
    printf("Give the name of the person from your family that you want to apply: ");
    scanf("%s",chosenperson);
    printf("\nYou chose: ");
    for(i=0;i<familymembers;i++){
    if(strstr(chosenperson,tmp.name)==0){
        printf("%s",tmp.name);
        apply=1;
    }
}
    if(apply==0){
        printf("\nThe selected name is not on the list");
        return;
    }
    printf("\nChose a time between 8:00 and 17:00: ");
    float timez;
    int hour;
    int minute;
    scanf("%f",&timez);
    if(timez>=8.00&&timez<=17.00){
        hour=timez;
        minute=(timez-hour)*100;
        if(minute>59){
            printf("Minutes are placed wrong");
            return;
        }
        printf("\nYour application to go out from %f to %f is accepted!",timez,timez+2);
        permission=1;
    }
    else{
        printf("You have chosen the wrong time");
        return;
    }
}




void control(){
    permit();
    struct citizen s[50];
    SYSTEMTIME d;
    GetLocalTime(&d);
    int g=permission;
    for(int i=0;i<nr_people;i++){
        if(g==1){
            printf("\n The citizen with IDNR: %s   Date: %d/%d/%d  Time: %d.%d has applied to go outside",s[nr_people].idnr,d.wYear,d.wMonth,d.wDay,hour,minute);
        }
    }
}




void save(){
    struct citizen s[50];
 FILE *f;
 f=fopen("detyra_day.dat","w");
 if (f==NULL){
   printf("\n Error on the file");
   return;
   } 
 for(int i=0;i<nr_people; i++){
  fwrite(&s[i],sizeof(struct citizen),1,f);
  }
}




int main(){
  char selection;
  do{   
  printf("\n=============================");
  printf("\n 1 - Read and print the data from the file detyra_day.dat");
  printf("\n 2 - Add a citizen");
  printf("\n 3 - Change a citizen");
  printf("\n 4 - Create a Permit to go outside");
  printf("\n 5 - Control the permission");
  printf("\n 6 - Save");
  printf("\n 7 - Print all Permissions to go outside for all citizens and families");
  printf("\n 8 - Print the list of 10 citizens that asked for the permission the most and 10 that asked the least (exclude the ones that didn't asked at all)");
  printf("\n 9 - Exit");
  printf("\n-----------------------------");
  printf("\n Zgjedhja : ");
selection=getch();
switch(selection){
case '1':
   readPeopleInfo();
   break;
case '2':
   add();
   break;
case '3':
    change();
    break;
case '4':
    permit();
    break;
case '5':
    control();
    break;
case '6':
    save();
    break;
case '9':
    exit(0);
}
getch();
} while(selection!='9');
return 0;
}
```

After I press Run and try number 1 which is read and print it prints every person as 1 not as the struct says. For example I want to print it like this:

```
IDNR: H65328040Q
Name: Azbie
Lname: Gockaj
Birthday (YYYYMMDD format):19760328
ID_Family: 1
```

Instead I get:

```
INDR: Name: Lname: Birthday: ID_Family:
```

and then every person ordered

[This is the detyra_day.dat file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzlkn.png)

H65328040Q Azbie Gockaj 19760328 1

J70507042S Ledion Celaj 19970507 1

G70312202S Pellumb Osmani 19670312 2

H45827189P Albina Osmani 19740827 2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mcve], with emphasis on the ***minimal*** part. LAstly please learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Please post `data.dat` as _text_ in a code block here [vs. linking to an _image_]. That way, a responder can download your program _and_ data file, and run it if they so choose. Otherwise, anybody wishing to do so would have to enter the data manually [something they are unlikely to want to do].

Comment: What part did it crash on, start debugging it and find the line it crashed on... Do not start with posting the entire assignment and Expect stackOverflow to debug it for you get a debugger...

Comment: The error is that your data file is text, but your code is doing binary I/O.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{',  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `#include <dos.h> 
#include <windows.h>`  Last I checked, these two headers do not play well together.

Comment: regarding: `void read(){`  the function name: `read()` is a well known C library function.  Best to use a name that describes what is being read. suggest: `readPeopleInfo()`

Comment: the 'linked' input data is not sufficient to be able to exercise all the requirements of the question.

Comment: OT: regarding all the calls to `printf()` for displaying the menu:  much better to only call `printf()` once and each menu line be a separate string. similar to `printf( "%s\n", "first string"  "second string" etc

Comment: regarding:   `char selection;`  and `selection=getc();`  the syntax for `getc()` is: `int getc(FILE *stream);`  Notice the returned type is `int`, not `char`.  This is so it can recognize EOF.

Comment: OT: regarding: `} while(selection!='9');` and other statements:  for ease of readability and understanding: please insert a (reasonable) space: inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.  Note: the compiler does not care

Comment: in function: `save()` regarding; `printf("\n Error on the file");` Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` 2) when the error message is from a C library function should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` is made for this purpose.  Suggest: `perror( "fopen failed" );`

Comment: regarding; `float time;`  `time()` is a well known C library function name.  Best to use a meaningful name that is related to the function being accomplished or to what that variable is part of.

Comment: OT: regarding: `fwrite(&s[i],sizeof(struct citizen),1,f);`  when performing I/O, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  In this case: `if( fwrite( &s[i], sizeof(struct citizen), 1, f) != 1) { //handle error }`

Comment: OT: regarding this kind of statement: `scanf("%s",&name);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In the current statement, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.  2) when using `%s` always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because that specifier always appends a NUL byte to the input.  This avoids a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.

Comment: regarding: `while(fread(&s,sizeof(struct citizen),1,f))`  This will not work as the lines in the input file are not all the same length nor formatted exactly like struct citizen.  Suggest reading each line using: `fgets()`  then parse that line using `sscanf()`

Comment: Please clarify: `b- Add another citizen when you know the IDNR is unique`  especially as the citizen data read in from the input file is not uniquely saved in a table in memory

Comment: @CraigEstey I edited the code as you asked

Comment: @YunfeiChen No part of code crashed it is not syntax error it is logical error when I press compile and run and select 1 to read the data it reads all the data as one it doesn't separate IDNR Name Lname etc

Comment: @user3629249 I edited the code and tried to remove one of the libraries that you pointed but there is no difference for pirntf part it is easier for me to do it separately and the prof. asked me to do it this way xd. For error in file it didn't make any difference I tried
b- Add another citizen when you know the IDNR is unique... that means that when we add another citizen we are going to search for the IDNR (if he already exist in the list or not) -> if not then add him

Comment: @user3629249 "regarding: while(fread(&s,sizeof(struct citizen),1,f)) This will not work as the lines in the input file are not all the same length nor formatted exactly like struct citizen. Suggest reading each line using: fgets() then parse that line using sscanf()"
I don't understand this part can you do a code related to my code using this? 
Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a number of errors.

First, you need a *global* array of `struct citizen` instead of having a function scoped `struct citizen` in each function.

In `struct citizen`, `idNr` was too small to contain a 10 digit ID number. It has to be [at least] one more to account for the EOS char at the end of the string.

Using `fread` and `fwrite` to access the data file. They are for *binary* files, but you have a *text* file. You need to use `fscanf` and `fprintf` respectively.

Using (e.g.) a [function scoped] `char *name;`. This is a *pointer* to a `char` [array/string] and it is *uninitialized*. Change this to `char name[100];`

Using `strstr` instead of `strcmp`.

Use of `scanf` or `fscanf` was inconsistent. If you had compiled with `-Wall -Wextra` to enable warnings [`gcc`], they would have become apparent.

It's bad practice to intermix `getch` [`fgetc`] and `scanf` on the same stream.

For consistency, I've added a `prompt` function instead of the various `printf(...); scanf(...);` sequences for prompting the user.

You didn't really use your `struct birthday` in the code.

---

Here's the cleaned up code. Some basics have been tested, but there are still some issues I couldn't get to. In most places, I've used `#if 0` to denote your old code [vs. my new code]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifndef __linux__
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#endif
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef __linux__
#include <time.h>

int
getch(void)
{
    char buf[1000];
    int chr;

    if (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin) != 0)
        chr = buf[0];
    else
        chr = -1;

    return chr;
}

WINBASEAPI VOID WINAPI
GetLocalTime(LPSYSTEMTIME lps)
{
    time_t tod;
    struct tm *tm;

    tod = time(NULL);
    tm = localtime(&tod);

    lps->wYear = tm->tm_year + 1900;
    lps->wMonth = tm->tm_mon + 1;
    lps->wDayOfWeek = tm->tm_wday;
    lps->wDay = tm->tm_mday;
    lps->wHour = tm->tm_hour;
    lps->wMinute = tm->tm_min;
    lps->wSecond = tm->tm_sec;
    lps->wMilliseconds = 0;
}
#endif

int permission;
int hour;
int minute;
int nr_people;

struct birthday {
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};

struct citizen {
#if 0
    char idnr[10];
#else
    char idnr[10 + 1];
#endif
    char name[50];
    char lname[50];
    struct birthday birthday;
    int id_family;
};

#define CITMAX      50
struct citizen citlist[CITMAX];

char fname[] = { "detyra_day.dat" };

void
prompt(const char *str,char *buf)
{

    printf("%s: ",str);
    fflush(stdout);

    fgets(buf,100,stdin);
    char *cp = strchr(buf,'\n');
    if (cp != NULL)
        *cp = 0;
}

void
getbday(const char *buf,struct birthday *bday)
{
    sscanf(buf,"%4d%2d%2d",&bday->year,&bday->month,&bday->day);
}

void
loadPeopleInfo()
{
    struct citizen *s;
    char birthday[100];
    FILE *f;

    nr_people = 0;

    f = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1) {
        s = &citlist[nr_people];

        if (fscanf(f," %s %s %s %s %d\n",
            s->idnr,s->name,s->lname,birthday,&s->id_family) != 5)
            break;

        getbday(birthday,&s->birthday);

        nr_people++;
        if (nr_people >= CITMAX)
            break;
    }

    fclose(f);
}

void
printPeopleInfo()
{
    struct citizen *s;

    printf("\n========================================================\n\n");
    printf("\t\t Details of all citizen \n\n");
    printf("========================================================\n\n");

    printf("IDNR\t\tname\tlname\tbirthday\tid_family\n\n");

    for (int i = 0;  i < nr_people;  ++i) {
        s = &citlist[i];

        printf("%s\t", s->idnr);
        printf("%s\t", s->name);
        printf("%s\t", s->lname);

        struct birthday *bday = &s->birthday;
        printf("%4.4d%2.2d%2.2d\t",bday->year,bday->month,bday->day);

        printf("%d\t\n", s->id_family);
    }
    printf("========================================================\n\n");
    printf("Number of citizen = %d\n", nr_people);
}

void
add()
{
#if 0
    struct citizen s, s1;
#else
    struct citizen *s;
    struct citizen s1;
#endif
#if 0
    int nr_people = 5;
#endif
    int found = 0;
    char buf[100];

#if 0
    printf("\n Give the unique IDNR: ");
    scanf("%s\n", &s1.idnr);
#else
    prompt("Give the unique IDNR",s1.idnr);
#endif

    for (int i = 0; i < nr_people; i++) {
        s = &citlist[i];

#if 0
        if (s1.idnr == s->idnr) {
#else
        if (strcmp(s1.idnr,s->idnr) == 0) {
            printf("The citizen with this IDNR exist\n");
            found = 1;
            return;
        }
#endif
    }

    if (found == 0) {
        s = &citlist[nr_people];

        printf("The citizen with this IDNR doesn't 'exist\n");
        strcpy(s->idnr, s1.idnr);

#if 0
        printf("\nGive the name of the citizen: ");
        scanf("%s\n", s->name);
#else
        prompt("Give the name of the citizen",s->name);
#endif

#if 0
        printf("\n Give the lname of the citizen: ");
        scanf("%s\n", s->lname);
#else
        prompt("Give the lname of the citizen",s->lname);
#endif

#if 0
        printf("\n Give the birthday of the citizen in the format YYYYMMDD: ");
        scanf("%s\n",buf);
#else
        prompt("Give the birthday of the citizen in the format YYYYMMDD",buf);
#endif
        getbday(buf,&s->birthday);

#if 0
        printf("\n Give the ID of the family of the citizen: ");
        scanf("%d\n", &s->id_family);
#else
        prompt("Give the ID of the family of the citizen",buf);
        sscanf(buf,"%d", &s->id_family);
#endif

        nr_people++;
    }
}

void
change()
{
    struct citizen *s;
    char birthday[100];
#if 0
    char *idnr;
#else
    char idnr[100];
#endif

    printf("\n IDNR of citizen: ");
#if 0
    scanf("%s", &idnr);
#else
    scanf("%s\n",idnr);
#endif
    for (int i = 0; i < nr_people; i++) {
        s = &citlist[i];
        if (strcmp(s->idnr, idnr) == 0) {
            printf("\nGive the name of the citizen: ");
            scanf("%s\n", s->name);

            printf("\n Give the lname of the citizen: ");
            scanf("%s\n", s->lname);

            printf("\n Give the birthday of the citizen in the format YYYYMMDD: ");
            scanf("%s\n", birthday);
            getbday(birthday,&s->birthday);

            printf("\n Give the ID of the family of the citizen: ");
            scanf("%d\n", &s->id_family);

            printf("\n Changed succesfully.");
            return;
        }
#if 0
        printf("\n The change didn't happened.");
#endif
    }
#if 1
    printf("\n The change didn't happened.");
#endif
}

void
permit()
{
#if 0
    struct birthday bday;
#else
    struct birthday *bday;
#endif
    struct citizen *s;
    int age[nr_people];
    SYSTEMTIME d;

    GetLocalTime(&d);
    for (int i = 0; i < nr_people; i++) {
        s = &citlist[i];
        bday = &s->birthday;

        if (bday->month > d.wMonth ||
            (bday->month == d.wMonth && bday->day >= d.wDay)) {
            age[i] = d.wYear - bday->year;
        }
        else {
            age[i] = d.wYear - bday->year - 1;
        }
    }

#if 0
    char *name;
    char *lname;
    char *chosenperson;
#else
    char name[100];
    char lname[100];
    char chosenperson[100];
#endif
    int id_family;
    int i;
    int apply = 0;
    int familymembers = 0;

#if 0
    printf("Put your name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
#else
    prompt("Put your name",name);
#endif
#if 0
    printf("Put your lname: ");
    scanf("%s", &lname);
#else
    prompt("Put your lname",lname);
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: use strcmp instead of strstr
    for (i = 0; i < nr_people; i++) {
        s = &citlist[i];
        if ((strcmp(name, s->name) == 0 && strcmp(lname, s->lname) == 0 &&
            age[i] >= 18)) {
            printf("Your name is on the list and you are in the age to apply [%d]\n",age[i]);
            id_family = s->id_family;
            apply = 1;
        }
    }
    if (apply == 0) {
        printf("Your name is not on the list or you are not in the age to apply");
        return;
    }

    struct citizen tmp[nr_people];

    for (i = 0; i < nr_people; i++) {
        s = &citlist[i];
        if (id_family == s->id_family) {
            tmp[familymembers++] = *s;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < familymembers; i++) {
        printf("%d. name: %10s\n", i + 1, tmp[i].name);
    }

    apply = 0;

    prompt("Give the name of the person from your family that you want to apply ",chosenperson);

    printf("\nYou chose: ");
    for (i = 0; i < familymembers; i++) {
        if (strcmp(chosenperson, tmp[i].name) == 0) {
            printf("%s", tmp[i].name);
            apply = 1;
        }
    }
    if (apply == 0) {
        printf("\nThe selected name is not on the list");
        return;
    }
    printf("\nChose a time between 8:00 and 17:00: ");
    float timez;
    int hour;
    int minute;

    scanf("%f", &timez);
    if (timez >= 8.00 && timez <= 17.00) {
        hour = timez;
        minute = (timez - hour) * 100;
        if (minute > 59) {
            printf("Minutes are placed wrong");
            return;
        }
        printf("\nYour application to go out from %f to %f is accepted!",
            timez, timez + 2);
        permission = 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("You have chosen the wrong time");
        return;
    }
}

void
control()
{
    permit();
    SYSTEMTIME d;
    struct citizen *s;

    GetLocalTime(&d);
    int g = permission;

    for (int i = 0; i < nr_people; i++) {
        s = &citlist[i];
        if (g == 1) {
            printf("\n The citizen with IDNR: %s   Date: %d/%d/%d  Time: %d.%d has applied to go outside",
                s->idnr, d.wYear, d.wMonth, d.wDay, hour, minute);
        }
    }
}

void
save()
{
    struct citizen *s;
    struct birthday *bday;
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("detyra_day.dat", "w");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("\n Error on the file");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nr_people; i++) {
        s = &citlist[i];

        fprintf(f,"%s ", s->idnr);
        fprintf(f,"%s ", s->name);
        fprintf(f,"%s ", s->lname);

        bday = &s->birthday;
        fprintf(f,"%4.4d%2.2d%2.2d ",bday->year,bday->month,bday->day);

        fprintf(f,"%d\n", s->id_family);
    }

#if 1
    fclose(f);
#endif
}

int
main()
{
    char buf[100];
    int selection = 0;

    loadPeopleInfo();

    do {
        printf("\n=============================");
        printf("\n 1 - Read and print the data from the file detyra_day.dat");
        printf("\n 2 - Add a citizen");
        printf("\n 3 - Change a citizen");
        printf("\n 4 - Create a Permit to go outside");
        printf("\n 5 - Control the permission");
        printf("\n 6 - Save");
        printf("\n 7 - Print all Permissions to go outside for all citizens and families");
        printf("\n 8 - Print the list of 10 citizens that asked for the permission the most and 10 that asked the least (exclude the ones that didn't asked at all)");
        printf("\n 9 - Exit");
        printf("\n-----------------------------\n");

        prompt("Zgjedhja",buf);
        selection = buf[0];

        switch (selection) {
        case '1':
            printPeopleInfo();
            break;
        case '2':
            add();
            break;
        case '3':
            change();
            break;
        case '4':
            permit();
            break;
        case '5':
            control();
            break;
        case '6':
            save();
            break;
#if 0
        case '9':
            exit(0);
#endif
        }
#if 0
        getch();
#endif
    } while (selection != '9');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding: `#endif
#include <windows.h>`  the header file: `windows.h` is a microsoft windows header file, NOT a C library standard file. so those two lines need to be swaped

Comment: regarding: `WINBASEAPI VOID WINAPI` this will not compile under 'linux', suggest writing this whole answer for microsoft windows only

Comment: regarding; `sscanf(buf,"%4d%2d%2d",&bday->year,&bday->month,&bday->day);` this is showing the OP to not check the returned values from C library functions,  that is NOT the way to inform the OP about the correct way to code

Comment: regarding: `char *cp = strchr(buf,'\n');
    if (cp != NULL)
        *cp = 0;`  Much better to use a simple function call like: `buf[ strcspn( buf, "\n" ) ] = '\0';` which is exposed when the statement: `#include <string.h>` is used

Comment: @CraigEstey thank you so much I really don't understand some commands cuz I'm new in programming but I will try to search them on google and try to understand them. Most of the code worked (not all of it but I wanted only the first part tbh so great job). Once again thank you so much for helping me I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user3629249 I am using a windows so dw :) . I don't really know the function that you stated strcspn but I will try it. Thank you

Comment: when you don't know a function, look it up on the internet.  For instance: with the search text: `man page for strcspn in c` the result is [strcspn function](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcspn)